# How to set SSRS report page size from ReportViewer.cs page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

In my case I will only know the reports page size at run-time. Hence I need to be able to set the SSRS reports page size using C# code from the ReportViewer.aspx.cs page (from which I will be loading the report file).
please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://forums.asp.net/t/2053895.aspx?How+to+set+page+size+in+a+Report+viewer+in+Microsoft+ReportViewer+WebForms
this code will work:

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings pg=new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();
pg.Margins.Top = 0;
pg.Margins.Bottom = 0;
pg.Margins.Left = 0;
pg.Margins.Right = 0;
System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize size = new PaperSize();
  // If you need A5 size then try:
//size.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.A5;
// pg.PaperSize = size;


this.reportViewer1.SetPageSettings(pg);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

More docs at MSDN where you can follow the links to get all sorts of details about the PageSettings class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.setpagesettings.aspx